# Переписать значение в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: javascript

Как массиве найти нужный id и обновить значения внутри объекта?

```
array = [
{id: 0, name: name1, email: email1}, 
{id: 1, name: name2, email: email2},
{id: 2, name: name3, email: email3}, ...,
{id: n, name: name4, email: email4}]

function UpdateUser(id, name , email) {
    for (id in array) {
        usersData[id].email = email;
        usersData[id].name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var usersData = [
  {id: 0, name: name1, email: email1}, 
  ...
];

function UpdateUser(id, name, email) {
  for (var index = 0; index < usersData.length; index++) {
    if (usersData[index].id == id) {
      usersData[index].email = email;
      usersData[index].name = name;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```